# Laravel relationship in Datatables results in getForeignKey() error

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I've been trying for 1 day now to make the Laravel column search work on the relationship data.

I have two tables 'customers' and 'addresses', a Customer model and an Address model and also the relationships.

Relationship testing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwDYZ.png

Address Model Relationship:

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

Customer Model Relationship:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

Datatable Controller:

```
return DataTables::of($customers)
    ->addColumn('address', function (Customer $customer) {
        return $customer->address->name;
    })
    ->make(true);
```

Address Schema:

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('city');
    $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Customer Schema:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('alias');
    $table->decimal('multiplier',8,2);
    $table->string('email');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

JS:

```
columns: [
    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
    { data: 'name', name: 'name'},
    { data: 'address', name: 'address.name'},
    { data: 'multiplier', name: 'multiplier' },
    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' }
],
```

Everything looks fine to me and I really can't find out the issue when it comes to filtering per column  the relationship data.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::getForeignKey()
```

A way of fixing this is adding `->get()` to the controller but that will stop any Datatable pagination in the AJAX call and make everything slower as it queries and outputs the whole table.

Live results on:

http://ec2-35-178-196-9.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (write something at the bottom of the City column and press enter -> check Network tab and open the 500 error ajax link) or just switch pages.

How do I make Laravel column search work with relationship data?

Answer (score -1):

```
public function address() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'customer_id', 'id');
}
public function customer() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'id', 'customer_id');
}
```

Comment: On your DataTable Controller, try
{ return $customer->address()->name; }

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users